# Method call in html python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, list, function

I have a simple code:

```
liczby = [
    159,
]


def main():
    jeden_watek = []
    cztery_watki = []
    cztery_procesy = []
    cpu_procesy = []

    for _ in range(5):
        start1 = timeit.timeit(For1Thread, number=1)
        czas_dla_1_watek = round(start1, 3)
        jeden_watek.append(czas_dla_1_watek)
        print(f' Time taken with 1 thread: {start1: .3f} second(s)')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and I'm saving my results in a table. After this I have to save a variable in html.
My question is: how to call a method (`def`) in html code below:

```
html_raport = '''
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
value1 = str(jeden_watek[0])
'''
```

Python is showing an error: in this line

```
value1 = str(jeden_watek[0])
```

becasue '"jeden_watek" is not definedPylance'

How can I fix it, thank you.

Comment: You need to make `jeden_watek` a global variable.

Comment: @Barmar - ok so I can make them out of "main()" or just make a variable as global, yes?

Comment: It depends on whether you want to re-initialize them when you call `main()`. If you do, keep the assignments there and add `global jeden_watek`.

Comment: You can also put `html_report` inside the main function or pass `jeden_watek` as parameter to your html-report-function.